# Return result from asynchronous callback function

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, return-value, asynccallback

I have seen lots of posts on stackoverflow regarding getting the returned value of an asynchronous call in a callback function but I would like to know if I could get the result without going much inside the callback.

For Eg:
**Current Scenario**:

```
myFunc(arg1,arg2, mycallback);
..
function mycallback(values)
{
//Process values
alert(values);
}
```

**What I would like to have**:

```
var returnedValues = myFunc(arg1,arg2, function mycallback(values)
{
return values;
});

// Now I would to use the returnedValues here...
```

Is the above scenario possible? Kindly let me know.

Cheers.

Comment: You want a Future...

Comment: All the posts you saw probably gave the same answer that this can not be done.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that, what you could do is make use of [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Quote: **...I could get the result without going much inside the callback.**

If you are concerned about the [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/), that is something you can mitigate by using promises:

Example from [bluebird library](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird):

You should use promises to turn this:

```
fs.readFile("file.json", function(err, val) {
    if( err ) {
        console.error("unable to read file");
    }
    else {
        try {
            val = JSON.parse(val);
            console.log(val.success);
        }
        catch( e ) {
            console.error("invalid json in file");
        }
    }
});

Into this:

    fs.readFileAsync("file.json").then(JSON.parse).then(function(val) {
        console.log(val.success);
    })
    .catch(SyntaxError, function(e) {
        console.error("invalid json in file");
    })
    .catch(function(e) {
        console.error("unable to read file")
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a promise library.
Here is implementation using jQuery promise

```
(function ($) {
    function myFunc(arg1,arg2){
          var defer = $.Deferred(),
              result=arg1+arg2; 
          defer.resolve(result);
          return defer.promise();
    }

    myFunc(1,2).then(function(result){
        console.log('result is: '+result)
        //manipulate result as you want
        result=result+1;
        showFinalResult(result);
    });
    function showFinalResult(result){
        alert(result);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gfmvgc8p/